# Cant call column in advance where query laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
$lists->where(function($query) {
    $price = Currency::change($query->curr->name_en,
                              Session::get('cur_name'),
                              $query->price
                             );

    $query->addSelect("dprice = $price");

    $query->whereBetween('dprice', [
        Session::get('price')['min'],
        Session::get('price')['max']
    ]);

    //$query->where('price', '>=', Session::get('price')['min'])
            ->where('price', '<=', Session::get('price')['max']);
});
```

be know curr is relation method

```
Undefined property: `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$curr`
```

Comment: You don't have object here yet, you create here query so you cannot in the middle of query tell Laravel to get its relationship when query has not been executed yet.

Comment: so how i can solve that

Comment: @AJamal You get the value you need with one query and then use it to build your second query.